# WPF How to make a custom combobox with a button inside to clear

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have made a simple combobox with a delete button inside. If the user clicks the delete button, the selectedItem of the combobox will be empty.

This is my original combobox: (I know, the stackpanel should be inside a button)

```
<TextBlock Text="ComboBox:"></TextBlock>
<ComboBox
     ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding Item}"
     DisplayMemberPath="Description"
     IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
     IsEditable="False"
     IsDropDownOpen="False">
 </ComboBox>
 <StackPanel
     Orientation="Horizontal"
     HorizontalAlignment="Right"
     MouseEnter="GridSplitter_MouseEnter" 
     MouseLeave="GridSplitter_MouseLeave">
         <Image
               Source="../Images/clos.png"
               Height="12" Width="15" Margin="0 0 20 4">
         </Image>
 </StackPanel>
```

My question: How can I make a custom combobox element, so that I don't have to repeat this code for every combobox I have to make. And the cleared value is the selectedItem.

It would be something like this:

```
<custom:ComboBoxWithClearance>
      ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding Item}"
      DisplayMemberPath="Description"
      IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
      IsEditable="False"
      IsDropDownOpen="False"
</custom:ComboBoxWithClearance>
```

Comment: Create a UserControl?

Comment: I don't really see the delete button in your code... is it just me?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about creating a UserControl

[How to Create a WPF User Control & Use It in a WPF Application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W)

Comment: Hi, link only answers are discouraged. Can you include most important parts from the link in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `UserControl` named "ComboBoxWithClearance" and add [dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property) (`ItemsSource`, `SelectedItem`) to the code-behind of this one.

You would then move your current XAML into the markup file of the `UserControl` and bind the properties to their corresponding custom dependency property that you have created:

```
<ComboBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
     ... />
```

After you have done this, you will be able to use your control in other views and set/bind its dependency properties to whatever you want, e.g.:

```
<local:ComboBoxWithClearance
  ItemsSource="{Binding ITEMS}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding Item}">
  ...
</custom:ComboBoxWithClearance>
```